# How to pull most recent date in the past in SQL

Tags: sql, date

I am looking for a sql query that display the most current date in the past. For example I have the following columns:

```
CLIENT          DATE
1234567890      2017-01-01
1234567890      2018-05-17
1234567890      2018-05-18
1234567890      2018-09-18
```

Desired output:

```
6173282305      2018-05-18
```

I have tried combinations of **getdate()** and **MAX()** to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks all.

Comment: What database are you using?  Sql server?  Can you show what you've tried?  Your keywords are correct...

Comment: SELECT  Client, Date
  FROM table
  where client = '1234657890' and Date < ( Select MAX(NEW_DATE) from table)

Comment: I don't see `getdate()` in that sql?  What is `new_date`?  From your post, I was thinking you would want something like this: `select client, max(date) from yourtable where date <= getdate() group by client`

Comment: Isn't the max date `2018-09-18` as it's greater than `2018-05-18`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `order by` and `fetch first`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date < current_date
order by t.date desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This is basically ANSI-standard syntax.  Some databases prefer `limit` or `top` to `fetch first`.  Some prefer `getdate()` or `sysdate` or something else for the current date.  But the logic is the same, even if the syntax varies a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(date) from t group by client having max(date) < getdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a windows function and a cte like this:

With cte as
(Select client,
Date,
 Row_number() over (partition by client order by date desc) as date_count
From [tableName])

Select *
 from cte
Where date_count = 1

That row_number syntax might be a bit off, but should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify SQL dialect. Here are a couple of methods one might use with SQL Server.

**Method A**

First, choose the two most recent records, and from those, choose the oldest record:

```
/* from the two most recent records, choose the oldest */
SELECT TOP 1
  [Client], [Date]
FROM (
      /* choose the two most recent records */
      SELECT TOP 2
        [Client], [Date]
      FROM [TableName]
      ORDER BY [Date] DESC) x
ORDER BY [Date] ASC
```

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38054/2

**Method B**

Find the largest date value and specify a filter to select all records with dates less than that.  From that group select the most recent date:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  [Client], [Date]
FROM [TableName]
WHERE [Date] < (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM [TableName])
ORDER BY [Date] Desc
```

Link to SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/38054/6